# Ошибка Spring Boot - Error creating bean with name

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Ситуация следующая. Spring Boot приложение. Имеется `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pr.hotels</groupId>
        <artifactId>hotels</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api-consumer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>api-consumer</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pr</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>booking</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

На локальной машине все работает прекрасно. Но при переносе на сервер возникает ошибка при запуске:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/booking##7927]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataGrubber': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'lastChangeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'lastChangeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'lastChangeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lastChangeRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
```

Поиски корня проблемы привели меня к тому что возможно в библиотеках в собранном WAR находится слишком много версий реализации jpa. Так и получилось. В /WEB-INF/lib/ я нашел множество библиотек так или иначе связанных с jpa. Вот они:

- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar

и т.д. Вот скрин с полным списком библиотек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проект принимал от другого человека и не могу сказать как это вышло, т.к в `pom` ничего лишнего не заметил. Не могу понять как теперь оставть только то что нужно и выбросить все лишнее и самый главный вопрос что здесь лишнее из jpa, что может конфликтовать?

Comment: Вообще у вас очень странный пом. Вы используете спринг бут, но при этом добавляете много лишних зависимостей, которые спринг бут в себя включает. Возможно, одно накладывается на другое, и в таком случае мавен выбирает младшую версию.

Comment: @aleshka-batman собственно в этом и суть моего вопроса, я понимаю что что-то гдето конфликтует.

Comment: уберите артефакты (spring-orm,jackson-databind,spring-web) для начала. Они все присутствуют в стартерах. javax.servlet-api тоже лишнее, но т.к скоуп провайдед на работу приложения не влияет (просто code smell в поме).